# Exporting a data from last year to csv returns an error

Tags: django, csv, datetime

I'm trying to get my data from last year. but my django returns an error when I do it.

The error is:

```
TypeError at /home/export_by_last_year/
export_by_last_year() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

@views.py

```
def export_by_last_year():
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    last_year = datetime.now().year - 1

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Level', 'Amount', 'Timestamp'])

    for i in Rainfall.objects.filter(timestamp__year=last_year).values_list('level', 'amount', 'timestamp'):
        writer.writerow(i)

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="rainfall.csv"'

    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view always takes as (first) parameter the `request, so:

```
def export_by_last_year(request):
    # …
```